# Yaml "must be a mapping" error in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

In an attempt to make my app container wait for my DB container to be up, I am trying to change my docker-compose file from this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_DATABASE: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_USER: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: <credentials here>

  mem:
    image: memcached:alpine
  
  web:
    build: <path/to/project>
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mem 
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: devel
      MEMCACHE_SERVER: 'mem:11211'
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_USER: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_ADDR: db-1
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

to something like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_DATABASE: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_USER: <credentials here>
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: <credentials here>
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  mem:
    image: memcached:alpine
  
  web:
    build: <path/to/project>
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      mem
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: devel
      MEMCACHE_SERVER: 'mem:11211'
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_USER: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD: <credentials here>
      DB_ENV_MYSQL_ADDR: db-1
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

I made various attempts to format the `depends_on` section correctly, but no matter what, I can't seem to make it work. Online yaml validators do't help either in figuring out how to fix the error.

I feel like I've tried all possible combinations of dashes and colons but none of them seem to work:

```
    depends_on:
      - db:
        - condition: service_healthy
      - mem:
```

```
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      - mem
```

```
    depends_on:
      db:
        - condition: service_healthy
      - mem
```

How can I have two entries in the `depends_on` section, with one of them having an additional sub-entry?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `condition: service_started` for the `mem` service as follows:

```
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      mem:
        condition: service_started
```

You can also check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on).

Answer (score 0):

Yaml can be mapped directly into a data structure. When you start a line with a `-` you are defining an entry in an array. When it's a string followed by a colon, it's the key of a key/value mapping. So:

```yaml
depends_on:
      - db
      - mem
```

Creates an array containing the elements `db` and `mem`. While:

```yaml
depends_on:
      db: {}
      mem: {}
```

Creates two empty map entries with the keys `db` and `mem`.

Comment: Ok, so... given this, how do I actually edit my file to achieve what I need? I still don't get it. Can you please provide an actual working example?